# Flashloan callFunction being called internally

Tags: solidity-0.5.x, defi, flash-loans

I had a chance to look at this [contract](https://gist.github.com/gwmccubbin/42851b94eeec954caa5aa1fac9778920).

```
contract Flashloan is DyDxFlashLoan {
    uint256 public loan;

    constructor() public payable {
        (bool success, ) = WETH.call.value(msg.value)("");
        require(success, "fail to get weth");
    }

    function getFlashloan(address flashToken, uint256 flashAmount) external {
        uint256 balanceBefore = IERC20(flashToken).balanceOf(address(this));
        bytes memory data = abi.encode(flashToken, flashAmount, balanceBefore);
        flashloan(flashToken, flashAmount, data); // execution goes to `callFunction`
    }

    function callFunction(
        address, /* sender */
        Info calldata, /* accountInfo */
        bytes calldata data
    ) external onlyPool {
        (address flashToken, uint256 flashAmount, uint256 balanceBefore) = abi
            .decode(data, (address, uint256, uint256));
        uint256 balanceAfter = IERC20(flashToken).balanceOf(address(this));
        require(
            balanceAfter - balanceBefore == flashAmount,
            "contract did not get the loan"
        );
        loan = balanceAfter;

        // Use the money here!
    }
}
```

In `getFlashloan()` it calls the line `flashloan` and the comment says

> execution goes to 'callFunction'

How does this work? is it somehow calling it internally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is an internal call.

The flashloan function calls operate on [DyDxPool implementation](https://etherscan.io/address/0x1e0447b19bb6ecfdae1e4ae1694b0c3659614e4e/advanced#code). After a couple of steps if everything is fine it will execute:

```
ICallee(args.callee).callFunction(
    msg.sender,
    args.account,
    args.data
);
```

Invoking `callFunction` from the `Flashloan` contract.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One thing i'm confused with is `args.callee`. I'm not sure why it can call `callFunction` in `Flashloan` contract when `args.callee` is the address of `DyDxFlashLoan` contract.

Comment: @bbusdriver That is because Flashloan is DyDxFlashLoan (Flashloan inherits from DyDxFlashLoan so they have the same address when deployed).